# Can I use "hole" as a verb in the context of making holes in metal plates?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice

Here is the sentence in question. please read on:

"The brand plates [which are metal] **get holed** and engraved and drivers and amplifiers get mounted."

I'm not sure if "get holed" can be used in this context. Is there a technical term for when machines make holes in metal plates?

Thanks,
Maryam

Comment: I have seen/heard it used that way, though it always seems a bit "odd".  More commonly, of course, the verb is used in golf, or to indicate, say that the hull of a ship was punctured.

Comment: ("Bored" would be the more "proper" verb, for the radio chassis scenario.)

Comment: How big are the holes in relation to the plate?  To me, *"holed"* (or *"drilled"*, or *"perforated"*) suggests quite small 'holes'.  If they are significant (as I infer from the OP quote), I think **machined** would be better.

Comment: The rules for the use of jargon among a group with a common area of expertise are very lax.  As long as the meaning of the atypical form is commonly understood within that expertise, you can use the language however you like.  Jargon is like a "Domain Specific Language" for spoken languages.  Note, though, that jargon is never intended for use in general discourse; it requires a context of common expertise.

Comment: "Bore", "drill", "machine", "punch"  all imply a method for making the holes. And that's fine if one wants to imply a method along with the sequence. They could then say, "The plates are *bored* and engraved ..." but if the intent is to say that "holes are made" without eluding to a method, then these are not good alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, it is correct. [Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hole) has a similar example:

> Two days later it was holed and drifting landwards with oil gushing out of its tanks.

But in technical(Metallurgical or Mechanical engineering) texts, **punching** (when using a die and press) and **drilling** (when using a drill to bore the sheet) are frequently used.

[Punching](http://www.unipunch.com/SystemCapabilities.aspx):

[image: punching]

[CNC Micro Drilling](http://www.datron.com/applications/micro-drilling.php):

[image: cnc micro drilling]

Comment: But "holed" for a ship is a slightly different sense, both because English has always given boats special treatment, and because the "holing" was presumably neither intended nor well-controlled.

Comment: @HotLicks: I'll have to hole up for a while and think about that.